# Check the Total, used and available Hard Drive Disk space in RED HAT Enterprise Linux 7.6

Tags: linux, server, command, redhat

Good afternoon !! you fine and healthy?  I hope so!

Guys, I've been looking for a command to RED HAT Enterprise Linux that can show me in the cleanest way possible:

```
disk-space:
total
used
available
```

What I've tried so far?

`fdisk -l | grep Disk` -> It is asking for admin rights and I don't have them.

Also:
Command:

```
dmesg | grep blocks

I've been looking i several websites and forums but this is the cleanest thing i found out there:
[    2.070965] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 125829120 512-byte logical blocks: (64.4                          GB/60.0 GiB)
[    2.071017] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] 20971520 512-byte logical blocks: (10.7                          GB/10.0 GiB)
[    2.071099] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] 1069547520 512-byte logical blocks: (547                          GB/510 GiB)
```

And this only show me the partitions and their total size.
Doesn't show the `used` and the `available`

I also found this command:

```
# btrfs fi df /data/
# btrfs fi df -h /data/
```

OUTPUT:

```
Data, RAID1: total=71.00GiB, used=63.40GiB
System, RAID1: total=8.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=4.00GiB, used=2.29GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

But they don't work for me, i don't know if i'm missing something
Please see more: [https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-disk-space-command/][1]

SERVER DETAILS:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
```

Thank's in advance for any help.

Comment: Probably do : `$ df -h`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need to display information about physical volumes. If so, one can use `pvs`.

```
[student@workstation ~]$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  rhel_rhel8 lvm2 a--  <31.00g    0
```

On the above example, I have a disk of 31Gb and no free space to extent my Volume Groups (`VG`). Take a look at the man page of `pvs` as well.